# c# マジックナンバーの使用を検出できるツール

Tags: c#

c#でマジックナンバーを使用している箇所を検出してくれるツールを教えてください。

たとえば、

if (a == 125) のような行を検出してくれるようなものです。

Comment: どういうものを指して「マジックナンバー」と言おうとしていますか？　大体分かる気もしますが、何かしら例示があると質問の意図が分かりやすくなると思いました。

Comment: if (a == 125) のような行を検出してくれればと思っています

Comment: 後からこの質問を見に来た人にとってコメントはなかなか見難いので、できれば質問を編集して追記してくださいませんでしょうか？　自分の質問は、質問下部の「編集」を押すことで自由に編集できます。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 参考1（本家StackOverflowでの類似質問です。ただし少し古いかもしれません）：  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337432/looking-for-a-regular-expression-to-identify-hard-coded-magic-numbers-in-source

Comment: 参考2（本家StackOverflowでの類似質問です） http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29533905/how-to-find-all-the-hardcoded-values-in-a-c-sharp-projectsolution

Comment: 参考3（本家StackOverflowでの類似質問です） http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490974/find-all-source-hardcoded-strings